# Customizing reference styles of sub-tables in LaTeX

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, subfloats

I create and reference to some sub-tables. The following show a minimum example.

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{Table}
        \begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \caption{Sub1}
            Something
        \end{subtable}

        \begin{subtable}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \caption{Sub2}
            \label{tab:sub2}
            Others
        \end{subtable}
    \end{table}

    Table~\ref{tab:sub2}
\end{document}
```

Instead of `Table I(b)`, I get `Table Ib`. How can I customize the reference style to add the parenthesis enclosing the number of sub-tables?